# How do you obtain the Halloween 2017 masks?

Tags: payday-2

In the [Halloween 2017 Event](http://steamcommunity.com/games/218620/announcements/detail/1453961083959105742) new masks were added to the game.

> **Seven Deadly Sins Masks**
>
> The Cursed Kill room comes with 7 sinful masks to collect. To get a mask you need to **open some safes** first so get cracking.

[image: Seven Deadly Sins Masks]

I already played the new Cursed Kill Room Heist plenty of times:

> We are releasing the Cursed Kill Room a limited time event heist. During the next two weeks you can go in and crack **open as many safes** as you can. The timer only counts down when you are not protecting a safe, so be fast when securing the loot. You can gain extra time by shooting cops.

Do I need to open the safes from this new heist? Or are they talking about the usual safes that drop randomly once per week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got my first mask and this is what you need to do:

1. Play the Cursed Kill Room heist (on any difficulty) and **open 4 safes**.
2. When you run back to the start, where you then have to press the button to end the heist, **stop in the long hallway right before you get back to the room you started in**. On the left wall, you will see this:

[image]

3. **Press the button** of the mask you want, wait a few seconds until it materializes and then **take the mask**. (This last part is import, you need to take it, ***just pressing the button is not enough***.)

As far as I can tell, you can do that on any difficulty and even see on the counter there how many safes you still need to crack. I did this solo with bots, it is enough time.